# Stack Machine with Strings

Tags: c, stack, pypy, vm-implementation, rpython

I'm making a stack based virtual machine in RPython using the PyPy toolchain to convert the RPython to C. So far I have 4 instructions.

1. EOP - End of Program
2. EOI - End of Instruction
3. PUSH - Push item onto the stack
4. PRINT - Print the top of the stack

My question is, how do you push a String to the top of the stack. Is it the same as when you push a number to the top of the stack or do I have to do something else when working with strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends. Do you want to push the *string*, or a *pointer to a string*? If it's the former, you have a problem, because the string will have variable length, unlike a pointer or a number. If it's the latter, you have to consider memory management aside from your stack.

Comment: ...which is irrelevant to RPython, the context in which the question was asked.  In the RPython case, you cannot mix plain integers with other objects like strings; the usual way to go about it is to create a base class and two subclasses, W_Int and W_String, which each contain the value as an integer or as a string.